# Is a 50-60 H/s hashing speed normal for an Intel Core i5 4200?

Tags: cpu-mining

I was trying to mine Monero using my CPU. I am getting a speed of about 50-60 H/s. Is this speed normally what you get while mining using CPU? I am on an Intel Core i5 4200 CPU.

Answer (score 3):

Seems normal. You can play with number of threads to try and get some more. Amount of CPU cache is very important as you need 2MB of it for 1 thread.

If comparing with other cryptocurrencies, note that it's a different mining algorithm (CryptoNight) and that's the reason why you're not getting similar to others like Bitcoin.